# chmod not doing anything in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, chmod

I've got a bash script that I want to make executable in Cygwin. So I ran `chmod 755 file.sh` but it does nothing. Here is the file before and after the chmod command:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 Myname None  234 Mar 29 17:05 file.sh
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. When I run your command on a given file I see `-rwxr-xr-x` as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out what the issue was. It's because I had changed my `/etc/fstab` file to fix another issue with file permissions, specifically I had it setup like this:

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,noacl,posix=0,user 0 0
```

but since it's causing problems, I've now restored it to its default state:

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0
```

And no more issues with chmod.